# Disk cache enable in Azure databricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am working with PySpark application using Azure Databricks, right now I need to enable Disk Cache. How can I enable this?

I found below command, but instead of running every time where can I maintain this command to execute like a boot-up every time:

spark.conf.set("spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled", "[true | false]")

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To enable disk caching in Azure Databricks, configure the `spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled` property.

To ensure this setting is applied each time your PySpark application initializes, configure it in the cluster settings:

Below are the steps:

**Step 1:** Go to "**Clusters**" in the sidebar.
[image]

**Step 2:** Click on the cluster name you want to configure. In the "**Spark Config**" section, add a new entry with the key `spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled` and value `true` or `false`.
[image]

[image]

You can use `spark.databricks.io.cache.enabled` as either **True** or **False**.

**Step 3:** Click the "**Confirm**" button to apply the changes.

**Results:**

[image]